# How to check mongodb is running or not while starting the C++ application

Tags: c++, mongodb, mongo-cxx-driver

I am beginner to c++. I have followed http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-cxx-driver/mongocxx-v3/tutorial/ this tutorial. they told to connect to a running MongoDB instance, use the `mongocxx::client` class. I have done like this

```
mongocxx::client conn_;
conn_ =  mongocxx::client(mongocxx::uri{uri});

      if(!conn_){
        std::cout<<"db is not started";
      }else{
        std::cout<<"db is  started";
      }
```

if the mongodb is not started, it has to print "db is not started" but the above code does not seems to be working.
Please suggest me how to check mongodb is running or not before starting the application

Answer (score 2):

In principle MongoDB is designed as a distributed system, which every component might fail. The best advice is to be prepared for each query you do against the database to fail.

If despite this, you still want to test it, the simplest way is to send a command to MongoDB. Use `mongocxx::database::run_command` to send an `{"ismaster" : 1}` command to the admin database.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the only way to do it, but I should work fine.
You can do something like this

```
bool conn_(){
    try{
    //createClient
    //getAnyDatabase
    //getAnyCollection
    return true;
    }
    catch(){
       return false;
    }
}
```

Or, You can run a [ping](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/ping/) command

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
 DBObject ping = new BasicDBObject("ping", "1");
 try {
       mongo.getDB("dbname").command(ping);
 } catch (MongoException e) {
       ...
 }
```